# Name of the deleted file in cloudtrail logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudtrail

I enabled the cloudtrail logs as explained here...

https://www.powerupcloud.com/visualizing-aws-cloudtrail-logs-using-ekk-stack/

When I upload a file, the filename is correctly mentioned in the logs.
But when I delete a file, there is no filename!

I will like to know why AWS is not publishing the name of the deleted file in cloudtrail logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug and apparently AWS team is working on it for last several years!

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=799831